# How does the app know which middleware function to use in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

My application has two middleware functions and I load them in using app.use() but how does the application know when to use which middleware?

In my app.js file I use two middleware functions namely, errorMiddleware and notFoundMiddleware.
notFoundMiddleware runs when I'm not able to get a particular page, But how does nodeJS know how to choose between errorMiddleware and notFoundMiddleware?

**app.js file**

```
require('dotenv').config()

//asymc erros

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const notFoundMiddleware = require('./middleware/not-found')
const errorMiddleware = require('./middleware/error-handler')


//middleware
app.use(express.json())

// routes
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.end('<h1>Store API </h1><a href = "/api/v1/products">product route</a>')
})
//product route
app.use(errorMiddleware)
app.use(notFoundMiddleware)

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const start = async() =>{
    try{
        app.listen(port,console.log("server is listening"))
    }
    catch(e){

    }
}
start();
```

**error-handler.js**

```
const errorHandlerMiddleware = async(err,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json({msg:'something went wrong, We are sorry for the inconvenience'})
}
module.exports = errorHandlerMiddleware`
```

**not-found.js**

```
const notFound = (req,res)=>{
    return res.status(404).send('Route does not exist')
}
module.exports = notFound
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects and have a `.length` property indicating the number of declared parameters or arguments. Express in this case is checking to see if there's exactly 4 declared, knowing that the first argument should be an error and that the middleware is an error handler.

You can view the code here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/router/layer.js#L62

Comment: Oh thank you, But what if two functions had an equal number of arguments?